# Why can't I install Deedle?

Tags: f#, nuget, deedle

I downloaded a `Git` repository to another machine and I am having problems installing `Deedle` from `NuGet`. I get this message:

```
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'Deedle.1.2.5' with respect to project 'Fractal10', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'
Gathering dependency information took 233.24 ms
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Deedle.1.2.5' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
Resolving actions to install package 'Deedle.1.2.5'
Resolved actions to install package 'Deedle.1.2.5'
Found package 'Deedle 1.2.5' in 'C:\Files\bitbucket3\VSProjects\Fractal10\packages'.
Package 'Deedle.1.2.5' already exists in folder 'C:\Files\bitbucket3\VSProjects\Fractal10\packages'
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'Deedle.1.2.5' does not exist in project 'Fractal10'
Executing nuget actions took 206.17 ms
Failed to add reference to 'Deedle'.
  A reference to C:\Files\bitbucket3\VSProjects\Fractal10\packages\Deedle.1.2.5\lib\net40\Deedle.dll could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.
Time Elapsed: 00:00:00.6169792
```

Any ideas on the cause of this problem?

Comment: Maybe try clearing your downloaded `packages` and try again, since it's complaining that it can't be installed because it already exists.